# How to add a circle within a method in java?

Tags: java, user-interface

```
public static void board(){ //Create's my board
    {
        JFrame board = new JFrame();
        board.setSize(400, 200 );
        board.setTitle("Quiz Board Game");
        Container pane = board.getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, columns));
        Color temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            if (i%2 == 0)
            {
                temp = col1;
            }
            else
            {
                temp = col2;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setBackground(temp);
                if (temp.equals(col1))
                {
                    temp = col2;
                }
                else
                {
                    temp = col1;
                }
                pane.add(panel);
            }
        }
        board.setVisible(true);
```

I have this code written in java,  I was wondering how i would add two circles so it would create a board with two pieces? Thanks.

P.S I'm new at java

Answer (score 0):

override the paintComponent(Graphics g) method.

```
// create Image 
Image i = new ImageIcon("//filepath").getImage();
int pointXForFirstPiece = 0; // update for the x position of where your piece will be
int pointYForFirstPiece = 0; // update for the y position

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // do the painting for the two objects here
    // paint image
    // create another image object as done above, and then 
    // rewrite the line below for the second piece
    g.drawImage(i, pointXForFirstPiece, pointYForFirstPiece, null);
}
```

hope this helps